# How to switch between useStates instead of adding new

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components

I need to switch between 3 of mine different components:

```
const [showOne, setShowOne] = useState(false);
const [showTwo, setShowTwo] = useState(false);
const [showThree, setShowThree] = useState(false);
```

So when showOne is clicked, the One component will show up, but when showTwo/showThree gets clicked, showOne will hide and component Two/Three will show up instead.

*Current solution:*

```
<div className="box" onClick={() => setShowOne(!showOne)}></div>
<div className="box" onClick={() => setShowTwo(!showTwo)}></div>
<div className="box" onClick={() => setShowThree(!showThree)}></div>

{showOne && (
             <One />
            )}
{showTwo && (
             <Two />
            )}
{showThree && (
             <Three />
            )}
```

**Current behaviour:**

When clicked `showOne` -> component **One** shows up, when after `showTwo` is clicked, component **Two** will be added under component **One**. (the same for showThree - Three)

**Expected Behaviour:**

Click `showOne` - shows **One**, click `showTwo` - **One** disappear and **Two** will shows up ( the same showThree - Three)

Answer (score 1):

Create a to show state.

```
const [toShow, setToShow] = useState(0);
```

You can set the initial state to 1 ,2 or 3 if you like.

and render the boxes as follows

```
{toShow ===1 && <One />}
{toShow ===2&& <Two />}
{toShow ===3&& <Three />}
```

Comment: I followed your post, but where I will setToShow ? is it in my onClick funtion ?